# c# deflatestream returning lots of null characters

Tags: c#, deflatestream

I am trying to use DeflateStream to inflate data from a web server. for some reason though, the byte array my function returns contains several null characters instead of whatever they are supposed to be. 
eg(space represents a null char)

```
       ge       603-595568599                     _web           :   msg
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong. Here  is my decompress function:

```
using (FileStream inFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (DeflateStream Decompress = new DeflateStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
    {
        //Decompress.Flush();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Decompress))
        {
            byte[] temp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
            {
                if (temp[i] < 10) temp[i] = 0x20;
            }
            r0 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? what would/could be the cause of this?

ETA:
using example code from the msdn article produces the same results

```
using (FileStream inFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create("packet.txt"))
    {

        using (DeflateStream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
            r3=string.Format("Decompressed: {0}", "packet");
        }
    }
}
```

here goes an example data

```
42 58 51 8C 6E 85 51 BC 31 40 04 ED 28 48 2C 06 A8 B8 3C BF 28 C5 AE 5A 2D B1 20 BF D8 3A 1B 42 59 41 28 33 43 33 03 03 13 D3 78 13 23 0B 73 53 CB A4 B4 34 D3 B4 34 03 0B 53 0B 93 B4 A4 34 8B A4 24 E3 14 D3 54 43 73 13 B3 54 23 4B 83 24 D3 E4 34 13 88 AE 5A 1B 7D B8 B1 B8 3D 51 94 5A 9C 5F 5A 94 9C 6A 57 91 99 96 66 A3 0F E7 A2 F8 0E 00 00 00 FF FF
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `UTF-8`-encoded? Have you tried an alternative like `ASCII`?

Comment: If you are decompressing why are you reading this in as text lines? It will be binary data, you need to read it in in `byte[]` blocks.

Comment: The example at [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) seems to suggest using `CopyTo` method. Are you sure you are using DeflateStream the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: Have you considered that your input file is wrong? I would suggest you approach this problem from a TDD methodology. Create Tests, create a compress/decompress pair of functions. Fix bugs.